# Ask for microphone on onclick event

Tags: javascript, recording, web-audio-api

The other day I stumbled upon with this example of a Javascript audio recorder:

http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/index.html

Which I ended up using for implementing my own. The problem I'm having is that in this file:

```
var audioContext = new webkitAudioContext();
var audioInput = null,
    realAudioInput = null,
    inputPoint = null,
    audioRecorder = null;
var rafID = null;
var analyserContext = null;
var canvasWidth, canvasHeight;
var recIndex = 0;

/* TODO:

- offer mono option
- "Monitor input" switch
*/

function saveAudio() {
    audioRecorder.exportWAV( doneEncoding );
}

function drawWave( buffers ) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById( "wavedisplay" );

    drawBuffer( canvas.width, canvas.height, canvas.getContext('2d'), buffers[0] );
}

function doneEncoding( blob ) {
    Recorder.forceDownload( blob, "myRecording" + ((recIndex<10)?"0":"") + recIndex + ".wav" );
    recIndex++;
}

function toggleRecording( e ) {
    if (e.classList.contains("recording")) {
        // stop recording
        audioRecorder.stop();
        e.classList.remove("recording");
        audioRecorder.getBuffers( drawWave );
    } else {
        // start recording
        if (!audioRecorder)
            return;
        e.classList.add("recording");
        audioRecorder.clear();
        audioRecorder.record();
    }
}

// this is a helper function to force mono for some interfaces that return a stereo channel for a mono source.
// it's not currently used, but probably will be in the future.
function convertToMono( input ) {
    var splitter = audioContext.createChannelSplitter(2);
    var merger = audioContext.createChannelMerger(2);

    input.connect( splitter );
    splitter.connect( merger, 0, 0 );
    splitter.connect( merger, 0, 1 );
    return merger;
}
function toggleMono() {
    if (audioInput != realAudioInput) {
        audioInput.disconnect();
        realAudioInput.disconnect();
        audioInput = realAudioInput;
    } else {
        realAudioInput.disconnect();
        audioInput = convertToMono( realAudioInput );
    }

    audioInput.connect(inputPoint);
}


function cancelAnalyserUpdates() {
    window.webkitCancelAnimationFrame( rafID );
    rafID = null;
}

function updateAnalysers(time) {
    if (!analyserContext) {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("analyser");
        canvasWidth = canvas.width;
        canvasHeight = canvas.height;
        analyserContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
    }

    // analyzer draw code here
    {
        var SPACING = 3;
        var BAR_WIDTH = 1;
        var numBars = Math.round(canvasWidth / SPACING);
        var freqByteData = new Uint8Array(analyserNode.frequencyBinCount);

        analyserNode.getByteFrequencyData(freqByteData); 

        analyserContext.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
        analyserContext.fillStyle = '#F6D565';
        analyserContext.lineCap = 'round';
        var multiplier = analyserNode.frequencyBinCount / numBars;

        // Draw rectangle for each frequency bin.
        for (var i = 0; i < numBars; ++i) {
            var magnitude = 0;
            var offset = Math.floor( i * multiplier );
            // gotta sum/average the block, or we miss narrow-bandwidth spikes
            for (var j = 0; j< multiplier; j++)
                magnitude += freqByteData[offset + j];
            magnitude = magnitude / multiplier;
            var magnitude2 = freqByteData[i * multiplier];
            analyserContext.fillStyle = "hsl( " + Math.round((i*360)/numBars) + ", 100%, 50%)";
            analyserContext.fillRect(i * SPACING, canvasHeight, BAR_WIDTH, -magnitude);
        }
    }

    rafID = window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame( updateAnalysers );
}

function gotStream(stream) {
    // "inputPoint" is the node to connect your output recording to.
    inputPoint = audioContext.createGainNode();

    // Create an AudioNode from the stream.
    realAudioInput = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    audioInput = realAudioInput;
    audioInput.connect(inputPoint);

//    audioInput = convertToMono( input );

    analyserNode = audioContext.createAnalyser();
    analyserNode.fftSize = 2048;
    inputPoint.connect( analyserNode );

    audioRecorder = new Recorder( inputPoint );

    zeroGain = audioContext.createGainNode();
    zeroGain.gain.value = 0.0;
    inputPoint.connect( zeroGain );
    zeroGain.connect( audioContext.destination );
    updateAnalysers();
}

function initAudio() {
    if (!navigator.webkitGetUserMedia)
        return(alert("Error: getUserMedia not supported!"));

    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({audio:true}, gotStream, function(e) {
            alert('Error getting audio');
            console.log(e);
        });
}

window.addEventListener('load', initAudio );
```

As you might be able to see, the **initAudio()** function (the one wich ask the user for permission to use his/her microphone) is called inmediately when the page is loaded (read the last line) with this method:

```
window.addEventListener('load', initAudio );
```

Now, I have this code in the HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function() {
  $("#recbutton").on("click", function() {
    $("#entrance").hide();
    $("#live").fadeIn("slow");
    toggleRecording(this);
    $(this).toggle();
    return $("#stopbutton").toggle();
  });
  return $("#stopbutton").on("click", function() {
    audioRecorder.stop();
    $(this).toggle();
    $("#recbutton").toggle();
    $("#live").hide();
    return $("#entrance").fadeIn("slow");
  });
});
</script>
```

And as you can see, I call the **toggleRecording(this)** function (the one wich starts the recording process) only after the #recbutton is pressed. Now, everything works fine with this code BUT, the user gets prompted for microphone permission as soon as the page is loaded and I want to ask them for permission to use the microphone ONLY AFTER they clicked the #recbutton Do you understand me? I tought that if I remove the last line of the first file:

```
window.addEventListener('load', initAudio );
```

and modify my embedded script like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function() {
  $("#recbutton").on("click", function() {
    $("#entrance").hide();
    $("#live").fadeIn("slow");
    initAudio();
    toggleRecording(this);
    $(this).toggle();
    return $("#stopbutton").toggle();
  });
  return $("#stopbutton").on("click", function() {
    audioRecorder.stop();
    $(this).toggle();
    $("#recbutton").toggle();
    $("#live").hide();
    return $("#entrance").fadeIn("slow");
  });
});
</script>
```

I might be able to achieve what I wanted, and actually I am, the user doesn't get prompted for his/her microphone until they click the #recbutton. The problem is, **the audio never get's recorded**, when you try to download it, the resulting WAV it is empty.

How can I fix this?

My project's code is at: https://github.com/Jmlevick/html-recorder

Comment: what browser do you use?

Comment: Chrome, the example only works in the most recent versions of Chrome

Comment: Try to go on chrome://flags/ and see if there is a setting that you can change. And even if not. Try to run your example again after you visited this site. It sounds stupid but I had the same problem with audio recording and for some weird reason, just visiting this site, made the recordings work. Would be interesting to know, if you experience the same.

Comment: Hmmm but the recording works fine, the problem is, the "ask for microphone" event can't be binded to an onclick and get audio. but if you run the example exactly as it is, it works fine.

Comment: So it doesn't even ask the user? Then i misread your question. I thought you would still be able to do the recording, but the wav-file is empty.

Comment: No, look: The example is set to ask for permission to use the microphone when the page loads. The user permits it, and then he/she can record audio and export it to a file, everything works. What I want to do is to trigger the "ask for microphone permission" event only after the user clicked a button, and when I try to do that as I explain in the question, the audio file returns empty.

Comment: I understand that, but does the user still get asked for permission or does it not even reach the function `initAudio`? Can you save the wave file? And is this wav file filled with zeros (but has an appropriate size or lets say length) or is it just empty like zero seconds long?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31801/discussion-between-jmlevick-and-basilikum)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an elegant & easy solution for this (or at least I see it that way):

What I did was toss **"main.js"** and **"recorder.js"** inside a getScript call that is executed only when a certain button (#button1) is clicked by the user... These scripts do not get loaded with the webpage itself until the button it's pressed, but we need some more nifty tricks to make it work the way I described and wanted above:

in **main.js**, I changed:

```
window.addEventListener('load', initAudio );
```

for:

```
window.addEventListener('click', initAudio );
```

So when the scripts are loaded into the page with getScript the **"main.js"** file now listens for a **click event** in the webpage to ask the user for the microphone. Next, I had to create a hidden button (#button2) on the page wich is fakely clicked by jQuery exactly right after the scripts are loaded on the page, so it triggers the "ask for microphone permisson" event and then, just below that line of code wich generates the fake click I added:

```
window.removeEventListener("click", initAudio, false);
```

so the "workflow" for this trick ends up as follows:

1. User presses a button wich loads the necesary js files into the page with getScript, it's worth mentioning that now the "main.js" file listens for a **click** event on the window instead of a **load** one.
2. We have a hidden button wich is "fakely clicked" by jQuery just in the moment you click the first one, so it triggers the permisson event for the user.
3. Once this event is triggered, the click event listener is removed from the window, so it never fires the "ask for permisson" event again when the user clicks anywhere on the page.

And basically that's all folks! :) now when the user goes into the page he/she never get asked for microphone permisson until they click a "Rec" button on the page just as I wanted. With one click of the user we do 3 things in jQuery, but for the user it seems like nothing happened other that the "microphone permisson message" appearing on the screen instantly right after they click the "Rec" Button.

Comment: im glad this worked for you, but wow, this is needlessly convoluted. the other answer is much better

Answer (score 1):

No, your problem is that getUserMedia() has an asynchronous callback (gotMedia()); you need to have the rest of your code logic in the startbutton call (the toggleRecording bit, in particular) inside that callback, because right now it's getting executed before getUserMedia returns (and sets up the audio nodes).