# How to mute microphone after recording using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, audio-recording, microphone, mute

I have using an application to record audio which uses the javaScript code but after recording its mic will never disable.

So please suggest me that how to mute/disable microphone using javaScript?

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17123263/ask-for-microphone-on-onclick-event

Comment: use the muted property - set it to off.

Answer (score 7):

You can stop stream created on MediaRecorder:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio:true,video:false}).then(function(stream)
{
    recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
});
recorder.stream.getAudioTracks().forEach(function(track){track.stop();});
```

Comment: I've edited your question to use multi-line code formatting. I noticed that you use `recorder` outside of where you call `new MediaRecorder`. Is that correct?

Comment: It's a little example. You can set a global variable outsid that function and using it for others method.

Comment: This does not actually mute. This stops the stream. This could be a problem is some scenarios, for example when you want to unmute. Check the @darma answer for details

Answer (score 4):

The [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42986414/414458) is not ideal because the tracks are actually ended and cannot recover after you called `track.stop();`, so you cannot unmute for example. Better:

**Mute**

```
stream.getAudioTracks().forEach(function(track) {
    track.enabled = false;
});
```

**Unmute**

```
stream.getAudioTracks().forEach(function(track) {
    track.enabled = true;
});
```